# Best way to structure a NoSQL payment schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, nosql, schema

I designed this schema/structure for an online marketplace where users can buy products from sellers.

Each seller has an account (`Funds`) where they can view their payments, withdrawal history, and user refunds.

However, there are a two issues I have noticed in this design.

1. `payment` is repeated in the `OrderPayments` and `Orders` collections.
2. `date` is repeated in the `Withdrawals` and `Payments` collections.

Should I remove the repeated fields, or does it not matter?

Also, are there any other flaws with this design? Thank you.

[image: Proposed backend schema]